# PostgreSQL - How to return an array of key-value pairs in a funtion

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to return an key, value list from a PostgreSQL function.
I have table of movies, and another table of artists.
I want to return something like:

```
{[movie_name1, [artist1, artist2, artist3]],[movie_name2, [artist1, artist4, artist5]}.....}
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Declare your function as `returns jsonb` then you can return a JSON value that contains exactly what you want.

```
return '[
         {"movie_name1": ["artist1", "artist2", "artist3"]},
         {"movie_name2": ["artist1", "artist4", "artist5"]
       ]'::jsonb;
```

Or alternatively return a table:

```
returns table (movie_name text, artists text[])
```

So one row per movie